# How to insert unique objects in realm?

Tags: android, realm

Need to insert objects into my realm, and so far things work good.

```
    public void markAsFavorite(View view)
    {
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        favorite f1 = realm.createObject(favorite.class);
        f1.setMovieName(m_name);
        f1.setRelease_date(release_date);
        f1.setPoster_link(poster_link);
        f1.setID(id);
        f1.setVote_avg(vote_avg);
        f1.setSynopsis(synopsis);
        f1.setTrailer(fn_trailer);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

**favorite.class:**

```
    public class favorite extends RealmObject
{
    private String movieName,release_date,poster_link,synopsis,trailer;
    private double vote_avg;

    @PrimaryKey
    private int ID;

    public int getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getMovieName()
    {
        return movieName;
    }

    public void setMovieName(String movie)
    {
        this.movieName = movie;
    }

    public String getRelease_date()
    {
        return release_date;
    }

    public void setRelease_date(String release)
    {
        this.release_date = release;
    }

    public String getPoster_link()
    {
        return poster_link;
    }

    public void setPoster_link(String poster)
    {
        this.poster_link = poster;
    }

    public String getSynopsis()
    {
        return synopsis;
    }

    public void setSynopsis(String syn)
    {
        this.synopsis = syn;
    }

    public String getTrailer()
    {
        return trailer;
    }

    public void setTrailer(String trail)
    {
        this.trailer = trail;
    }

    public double getVote_avg()
    {
        return vote_avg;
    }

    public void setVote_avg(double vote)
    {
        this.vote_avg = vote;
    }


}
```

Now, **the problem is** : I need to insert only unique items in the record,as you can see,I've defined `ID` as primaryKey.

```
@PrimaryKey
private int ID;
```

Is it possible to insert an object by making sure the same `ID` does not exist in realm?

---

**EDIT-1**

In a similar question, I found this solution:

```
   public boolean checkIfExists(String id){

    RealmQuery<Data> query = realm.where(Data.class)
            .equalTo("id", id);

    return query.count() == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

However, did not work in my implementation, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public boolean checkIfExists(String id){

RealmResults<Data> query = realm.where(Data.class)
                    .equalTo("ID", id).findAll();

        return query.size() == 0 ? false : true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary key is forced to be unique, then if you try to insert an object with an id that already exists, the insertion operation will fail and realm will raise an exception.

If you want to check other fields different from the one used as primary key, the unique constraint is not available yet, then the only way is to check them manually (just before the insertion) using a query with a concatenation of "equalTo"s on the fields that you need to be unique.